# shellscripts in Makefiles do not work as expected

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I found many answers here and elsewhere on the topic, but none that worked. Please help me out here.

I need to set some environment variables, which is partly done in some scripts, called from a master script, partly directly. Here is a minimal Makefile that shows the unwanted behaviour:

```
FC := ifort

SHELL := /bin/bash

some_target: load_ifort
    $(FC) file.f

load_ifort:
    source /usr/local2/bin/ifort-compilervars.sh ia32
    export LM_LICENSE_FILE=/usr/local2/misc/intel2013/flexlm/server.lic
```

if I call make, I get an "ifort: command not found" error. If I execute the two comamnds by hand on the command line before calling make, ifort is found and everything is good.

What am I missing???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line in a recipe gets executed in a separate subshell.  So you create one shell which sources the `.sh` file, then exits and forgets everything, then another shell which starts with a clean slate.

The straightforward solution in your case would be to collect all these commands in a single variable.  I have factored out the `LM_LICENSE_FILE` assignment because that can be done in Make directly, but you could include that in the `FC` variable as well.

```
LM_LICENSE_FILE := /usr/local2/misc/intel2013/flexlm/server.lic
export LM_LICENSE_FILE

FC := source /usr/local2/bin/ifort-compilervars.sh ia32; \
    ifort

some_target:
    $(FC) file.f
```

If the shell commands can be straightforwardly run by Make as well, you could `include` them, or perhaps translate the `sh` file into Make commands by a simple script.

Another option would be to create a simple wrapper in your `PATH`; maybe call it `fc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /usr/local2/bin/ifort-compilervars.sh ia32
ifort "$@"
```

then just use `fc` where you currently have `$(FC)`.  (If the `ifort-compilervars.sh` file contains Bash constructs, in spite of the name, you should change the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) to `#!/bin/bash`.)

Comment: `source` is a bash extension.  If you want to write a script using `/bin/sh`, POSIX shell, you should use `.` instead.  If you want to use `source`, your script should start with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: And the same in the makefile assignment of `FC`... `make` always invokes `/bin/sh` to run recipes, regardless of what the user's interactive shell is set to.

Comment: Except the OP explicitly has `SHELL := /bin/bash`.

Comment: The first line contained the information I was missing. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, only one-liner shell commands "work".  From the comment about "bash", it seems likely you are using GNU make. In your example, the word "source" is not found in the GNU make manual's [index](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Concept-Index).  (If you found this in a working example, it would be helpful to start from that).  There are two types of variables of interest:

- makefile variables, which live in the make program
- environment variables, which are "exported"

The latter would include $PATH, which is used to find programs.  For updating that, you do need shell commands.  But (lacking some special provision in the make program), exported variables from a shell script are not passed *up* into the make program and made available for the next line of the makefile.

You could reorganize the makefile to provide a rule which combines the source command and other initialization into a shell command which then recurs (carrying those variables along) into a subprocess which would then do the compiles.  Something like

```
build:
    sh -c "source /usr/local2/bin/ifort-compilervars.sh ia32; \
           export LM_LICENSE_FILE=/usr/local2/misc/intel2013/flexlm/server.lic; \
           $(MAKE) some_target"
some_target: load_ifort
    $(FC) file.f
```

Comment: Why are you adding `sh -c` here?  Seems like a useless extra invocation of the shell...?

Comment: See my comment below to triplee about `source` vs. `.`.  You need to use `.` here not `source`, for portability.

Comment: Some shell programs may/may not handle a string of commands without the "-c" option.  I added it from habit.

Comment: Agreed - "source" is a bash extension (borrowed from csh).  I was limiting my comments to the make program.

Comment: There is no `/bin/sh` program in existence that doesn't handle a string of commands.  Make works by invokes the shell with the `-c` option to run commands already.  Basically, you are running `sh -c 'sh -c "source /usr/...; make some_target"'` which is redundant and inefficient.  And confuses people who aren't sure how things work.

Comment: I'm not going to argue, but did just now run a quick check with dash, and it failed when I took out the "-c".  If you like, I'll add this to my to-do list for webpage topics.

Comment: You can't take out just the `-c` option.  That's an illegal shell command: it's treating the script as the name of a file to execute.  You have take out the entire `sh -c` and the outer quotes as well.  It should just be: `. /usr/local2/bin/ifort-compilervars.sh ia32; export LM_LICENSE_FILE=/usr/local2/misc/intel2013/flexlm/server.lic; $(MAKE) some_target`

Comment: Back up a couple of comments: you stated that make invokes the shell is `-c`.  I can agree for GNU make, NetBSD 5, Solaris and HPUX, but not (I just checked by a simple makefile which does a ps, and looking at the process-id chain) AIX 5.3, 7.1 as well as FreeBSD 10.   For those cases, "make" is the parent process of the "ps", which seems to preclude an intervening "sh -c" as you suggest.

Comment: You can't use a simple command and get a valid test.  Many versions of make will, as a performance improvement, invoke all "simple enough" commands directly rather than invoking the shell.  That is, if make can determine how to invoke your command directly while still getting identical functionality without the shell, it will.  Otherwise make will invoke the shell.  Anyway, it's always safe to write the command in a recipe directly, you never need `/bin/sh -c`.  POSIX requires `make` to run your command "as if" by the shell.  I've never seen any version of make where this failed.

Comment: Well, then - when you've retested AIX, you might have an explanation that addresses the observation which I made.  Here's the makefile which I used:
    all:
        if true; then echo first; echo second; ps -efl; fi"

Comment: I don't understand what point you're trying to make.  My statement was, and is, that you don't need to add an explicit `sh -c` to your make recipes in order to write shell scripts of any complexity: they will work properly without it.  So you wrote a recipe containing a shell if-statement, without using `sh -c`, and it worked properly, just as expected.  What are we discussing, exactly?

Comment: If you're asking why AIX make doesn't show a shell, I have no idea and I'm not interested in figuring it out.  Maybe IBM created a "shell library" which parses shell command syntax and they link it with both their `/bin/sh` and their version of `make` so they can run shell scripts directly from `make` and don't need to fork a shell.  It doesn't really matter: what matters is that you don't need to add an explicit `sh -c` to your recipes, in order for them to run properly.  Even with AIX `make`.